# Calculating stack top address in 8086

Tags: stack, x86-16

If the stack segment register of an 8086 contains 1234H and stack pointer register contains 4321H , what is the physical address of the top of the stack?

How will I calculate this?

Comment: http://www.internals.com/articles/protmode/realmode.htm

Answer (score 4):

The 8086 calculates a 20-bit physical address by taking the SS register and shifting it left by 4. To this is added the SP offset. In your example:
SS is shifted left by 4 to give 12340H.
SP (4321H) is added in to give 16661h.

Answer (score 1):

Stack TOP address= SS*10H + SP